# Node.JS CRUD Delete operation

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm working on node.js CRUD code with MongoDB. The app is to allow a user to upload photos, edit details and delete the photo on the DB. I can't seem to get the Delete part of the code working. It should route the user back to /photos after deleting the picture.

Comment: Can u paste ur findByIdAndRemove method , also do u see any errors in ur terminal or browser console. Place some console logs in ur code and see whether the endpoint is getting hit or not etc. ... Thank you

Comment: Also the method type is get - method="get"  for your delete button may be try changing ur endpoint to - router.get('/delete/:photoid', function(req, res){

Comment: @zenwraight where/how do you want me to place the console logs? I tried to change the method to get but still getting error. See updated console error.

Comment: @zenwraight findByIdAndRemove method is from Mongoose found here - http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#findbyidandremove_findByIdAndRemove

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your form, you are sending `GET /photo/delete/{id}` request, while what you are defining on server-side is `DELETE /photos/delete/{id}` endpoint.
To get it to work, both HTTP method and URI have to match.
Unfortunately, HTML form currently doesn't support `DELETE` HTTP method, so the workaround for this would be using method-override middleware of express.

```
$ npm install method-override
```

Add methodOverride middleware on the server-side (in app.js).

```
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
...

app.use(methodOverride('_method'));

...
```

Change the method and URI in the HTML form, and add `_method` parameter to override HTTP method.

```
form(method="post" action="/photos/delete/" + photo._id + "?_method=DELETE")
    input#delBtn(type="submit" name="delButton" value="Delete Photo")
```

Here's more details on how you can use method-override middleware.
https://github.com/expressjs/method-override

Comment: I put in these updates but it still does not delete the record. Are you sure this should be --action="/delete/photoid" + photo._id -- ? On photo.js, the router get method is looking for /delete/:photoid

Comment: added app.js to original message

Comment: It might be bacause of the previous edit you made.
Server-side endpoint should be

`router.delete('/delete/:photoid', ...`

not

`router.get('/delete/:photoid', ...`.

`GET` method is for getting resources, and it shouldn't make any changes in db. To delete resources, you should always use `DELETE` method.

Comment: methodOverride middleware needs to be used in the app.js. not in the photo.js btw (edited my answer to specify that).

Comment: Just noticed HTML form action should be `"/photos/delete/" + photo._id + "?_method=DELETE"`, since photo router is mounted to `/photos` in app.js.

Comment: so like this?

 form(method="post" action="photos/delete/:photoid" + "?_method=DELETE")

Comment: i added the methodOverride to app.js

var methodOverride = require('method-override');
app.use(methodOverride('_method'));

and updated router.delete but still not working. 

router.delete('/delete/:photoid', function(req, res){

Comment: > so like this? form(method="post" action="photos/delete/:photoid" + "?_method=DELETE") .  
Should be `form(method="post" action="/photos/delete/" + photo._id + "?_method=DELETE")`.

Comment: Just want to thank you for continuing to help me here. Been scratching my head all night with this. I updated the form but it still doesn't delete the photo. I've updated the code above with the most recent edits. Can confirm method-override is a dependency - "method-override": "^2.3.10",

Comment: np:) Checked your last update. `form(method="post" action="photos/delete/" + photo._id + "?_method=DELETE")`. It's missing leading slash in the action URI.

Answer (score 0):

From this link:
[Are the PUT, DELETE, HEAD, etc methods available in most web browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165779/are-the-put-delete-head-etc-methods-available-in-most-web-browsers?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)
They have mentioned that HTML form would support only GET and POST method, while the XMLHttpRequest (i.e. Ajax) supports GET, POST, DELETE, PUT.

if ur form is using post method, your router should be `router.post('/delete/:photo_id', ...)`

In case that u want to use `router.get('/delete/:photo_id', ...)`, I may suggest u to use `<a href="photos/delete/" + photo_id + "?_method=delete">Delete Photo</a>`

Comment: just added app.js

Comment: You are using post method for your form, so the controller should be:

router.post('/delete/:photoid', function(req, res){ ... });